# Can emails from Marketing Cloud be sent via a relay?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, security, email-relay

The CSO of my company doesn't want us to use Marketing Cloud to employees unless the emails are sent through a relay ("...it needs to be authenticated and secured (and must have protections to prevent and protect against misuse and spoofing...")

Is this possible in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: I know at one point SFMC had an early adoption option for an SMTP relay, but judging from the fact that I see nothing on it at all anymore, I am not sure it is still available. Would be worth asking your account rep for sure though.

Comment: @Gortonington There was - but it isn't offered any more

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation @SeanGorman! I thought I was going crazy since I couldn't find ANY information on it anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SFMC does not offer SMTP relay.

However, I also don't see a need for this to achieve what your CSO is looking for. Emails sent from SFMC are both authenticated and secured.
Measures for ensuring this are a.o.:

- Your sender domains being TLS protected by default
- DKIM and SPF are in place to authenticate your domain and sender IP
- You can choose set up a custom DMARC record, enabling you to protect your customers and users of your website against false emails sent from your domain.

Comment: Lukas, at one point they did have an early adopter beta type program for it, right? Or am I going crazy?

Comment: @Gortonington - The only feature I remember (which is no longer offered) was allowing customers to relay transactional triggered sends via SMTP through the Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Hence the emails (transactional only - i.e. password resets, etc) originating and sent by external sources, could utilise the Salesforce Marketing Cloud infrastructure and deliverability framework. So indeed the other way around - not sending through a 3rd party SMTP relay.

Comment: @LukasLunow Thanks for this. Would a DMARC record also help with employees?

Comment: @SeanGorman - can you elaborate on the meaning of the word "help" in this context? :-)

Comment: I swore it was an option as I remember looking at it for internal emails for an old employer of mine, maybe I am going crazy...it is quite possible.

Comment: @LukasLunow Your third point you highlight that a Custom DMARC would enable us to protect customers and web visitors (I am right now looking to see what a DMARC is) but does this help with the perception of security for the CSO?

Comment: DMARC is a type of authentication to show ISPs that you are who you say you are: (https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-dmarc/). It will help with deliverability and help prevent spoofing, etc.

Comment: @Gortonington - Not according to the info I can find. Perhaps in the really old ET days. But that was before my era :-)

Answer (score 0):

SFMC Used to have a native SMTP relay feature it was really simple to get up and running. It sat in the Classic version of Email Studio. I believe this feature was discontinued when Classic was turned off.

The updated version of this that sits in Content Builder > Interactions > Triggered Sends but it is not as obvious how you set it up as it says it can be linked to an API but still relies on an associated data extension.